# Comparing player input against file of words

Tags: c++

student programmer looking for help with assignment. Jist of the program is to accept user character input, compare it to a file of legal three letter words. Have to output to screen what the user entered first and of course call multiple functions within functions. Been over a year since my last course (work trip overseas) so i've lost what little knowledge gleaned previously. Would be appreciative if someone could look at my code and tell me if i'm on the right path or way off. Specifically how do I test if the player typed lowercase letters and how do I compare the player letters against the file of legal words? I learn quickly if taught correctly. Ready for the red ink.
    #include 
    #include  //need this for string class
    #include //must have this to work with files

```
using namespace std;

//Declare Functions before the main??
char menu(); //function prototype for menu function
void processUserInput(); //function prototype for user input function
string findWords(string);
void readLegalWords();


int main()
{
cout<<"Welcome to Jellos TLW Game"<<endl;
char menuChoice = ' '; //variable to hold user's choice

//Call to menu function
menu();

system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

//Begin Function definitions
   //Start with menu function to prompt game player

```
char menu()
{
char menuChoice = ' '; //variable to hold choice
cout<<"Enter your Choice: "<<endl;
cout<<"    (F)ind Words"<<endl;
cout<<"    (Q)uit"<<endl;
cin>>menuChoice;

    if(menuChoice == 'F' || menuChoice == 'f')
    {
        /*call to function that will ask user to enter
        between 3-10 letters*/
        processUserInput();

    }
    else if(menuChoice == 'Q' || menuChoice == 'q')
    {
        cout<<"Thanks for playing Jellos TLW Game!"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
} //end of menu function


void processUserInput(char); //function definition
{
cout<<"Enter up to 10 lowercase letters."<<endl;
cout<<"You must enter at least 3 letters."<<endl;
cout<<"Enter a '-' to stop reading letters if you want less than  
10."<<endl;

//variable to hold string of letters
string inputLetters;
//read the letters
cin>>inputLetters;

if(inputLetters.size() >= 3 && inputLetters.size() <= 10 && inputLetters 
== '-')

   {    //display what the player typed in to screen on one line
    cout<<"you entered the following letters."<<inputLetters<<endl;
    //call to function to test the letters against legal 3 letter word 
 file
            //read into an array of legal 3-letter words.
    //

    findWords(string);//function call
    }

    else if(letters.size() < 3 && letters.size() > 10) //test the input
     {
         cout<<"Please enter between 3-10 lowercase letters."<<endl;
     }
 }


/* Test the following conditions are met
** at least 3 letters are entered
** no more than 10 letters are entered
** so long as 3 letters are entered a - will stop input
** all input is lowercase letter or - anything else will display error  
message

** once input is entered correctly the letters the player entered are 
displayed
back to him/her on a single line

** correct data will call to function findWords() which will fill an 
array with 
legal 3 letter words from player input and print the words if there are 
more than 1 

** findWords() will most likely have to compare string arrays (player 
input vs file that 
is read from another function */



//Need to test three conditions
//If player entered 3-10 letters
//If player entered lowercase letters
//do not know how to test whether player entered lower case letters
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `toupper()` or `tolower()` to convert the character to upper case or lower case so you only do one compare.

Secondly, if the file is not extremely huge, read the words into a vector of strings, e.g. `std::vector<string>`.

Input the player string.
Iterate through the vector, using `==` or `!=` to compare the player's text to the words from the file.

An option is to sort the words in the vector and use something like `std::lower_bound` to find the words.  If the vector is sorted, you don't have to search the entire contents.